# Induced new structures on Poincare dual manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, manifolds, fibre-bundles

["R. C. Kirby and L. R. Taylor, Pin structures on low-dimensional manifolds (1990)"](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kirbytaylorpin.pdf) shows

> Given a spin structure on $M^3$, the submanifold $\text{PD}(a)$ can be given a natural induced $\text{Pin}^-$ structure.

There $\text{PD}(a)$ is a smooth, possibly non-orientable submanifold in $M^3$ representing Poincare dual to $a\in H^1(M^3,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ (it always exist in codimension 1 case).

My take is that:

- (1) The normal bundle to the submanifold $\text{PD}(a)\equiv N^2\subset M^3$ for oriented $M^3$ can be realized as 
  determinant line bundle
  $\det T{N^2}$, so that $TM^3|_{N^2}=TN^2\oplus \det TN^2$.
- (2) For a general vector bundle $V$, there is a natural bijection between Pin$^-$- structures on $V$ and Spin-structures on $V\oplus \det V$.

> Question: Are there systematic and similar statements for the induced structures on the Poincare dual manifold? Say for, inducing any one from any of the other:

- Spin structure
- Spin$^c$ structure
- Spin$^h=\frac{\text{Spin} \times SU(2)}{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}$ structure
- $\text{Pin}^+$ structure
- $\text{Pin}^-$ structure

or whatever-related structures, of

- $\frac{\text{(S)Pin}^{\pm} \times G}{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}},$

where $G$ contains the same finite order-2 cyclic group ${\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}$ shared by the $\text{(S)Pin}^{\pm}$

in any dimension or in whatever other dimension?